# Is there a way to recalculate normal for every frame?

Tags: texturing, normals

So I just finished this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx5L8K99j10&t=1476s

However, the fact of the matter is that the direction of the some of the faces get inverted during the deformation part of the animation.  As such, in order too keep the normals in line for with the actual mesh at the time, I would like to recalculate the normals for every frame.

Is this possible, and if not is there some reason it wouldn't make sense...

Thanks.

Comment: Go in to edit mode. select all mesh 'A' and press ctrl+N

Comment: If some faces get inverted during animation fix the animation, don't fix the normals.